# Aria Isue on Vaadin Select

Tags: vaadin, wai-aria

When I scan the Vaadin Select component with the Axe Accessibility Chrome extension gives me the following critical error: "Elements must only use allowed ARIA attributes".

Element location:
vaadin-select-value-button

Element source:

```
<vaadin-select-value-button aria-haspopup="listbox" slot="value" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-labelledby="label-vaadin-select-0 vaadin-select-0" aria-required="false" aria-expanded="false"></vaadin-select-value-button>
```

Error:
ARIA attribute is not allowed: aria-required="false"

Is it ok that the role of the component is button?
How can i solve this?

The Vaadin's version is 23.1.2.

Comment: Did you try it with a screen reader? Was there any problem? Axe isn't the perfect tool to check for accessibility problems, especially with web components.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.